# Ag-Grid cellRenderer click event in Angular

Tags: components, click, ag-grid-angular, columnheader, cellrenderer

Please find the link below to help me troubleshoot. I am trying to implement click events for a button in the button-renderer component template and the component is used in a customColumn cellRenderer. I can't figure out why it's not showing the button-renderer template. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

https://angular-issue-repro2-k9ouxu.stackblitz.io

Comment: Please add the link to the editable Slackblitz page, where we can also take a look at your code. Alternatively, you may paste your code here, too

Comment: Sorry I attached the wrong link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-k9ouxu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I kept getting "Class constructor ButtonRenderer cannot be invoked without 'new'" error message

Comment: There was a compilation error on your slackblitz.. I have just fixed that on your link

Comment: Thank you @AkshAyAgrawal  Do you have any insights on why the template in buttonRenderer component is not shown?